# Use the shell method to find the volume between the line $y=4x+5$ and the parabola $y=x^2$.

Tags: calculus

> Use the **shell method** to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the line $y=4x+5$ and the parabola $y=x^2$ about the following lines.

d. The line $y=25$

I tried hard to solve it and it didn't work, it's a homework questiton,
I got the radius $25-y$ and height $4\sqrt y-\dfrac{25}{4y}$.

I get the volume $2740\pi$.

I was wondering if somebody can help me....

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing a plot of the region and identify the radius and height of the cylinder on the plot. I believe that your radius should be $$\begin{cases}\sqrt{y} - \frac{y-5}{4} & 1 \leq y \leq 25 \\ 2\sqrt{y} & 0 \leq y < 1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{y}-\frac{y-5}{4}$ is the height for $1<y<25$. The height is $2\sqrt{y}$ for $0<y<1$

Comment: @Lozenges you're right. I fixed my answer.